Ethereum: how to call Smart Contract functions directly with JSON-RPC method?
I need to execute and call http JSON-RPC ethereum node to get results without web3py or web3js. How to do that? I have read there is eth_call method, but I didn't find any examples with ABI how to use. Below is example with eth_getTransactionByHash.
import json
import requests
from web3 import Web3

w3 = Web3(Web3.HTTPProvider('https://eth-pokt.nodies.app'))
if not w3.is_connected():
    exit("w3 not connected")

# basic ERC-20: name(), symbol(), decimals() balanceOf()
abi = json.loads('[{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"name","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"string"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"decimals","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint8"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[{"name":"_owner","type":"address"}],"name":"balanceOf","outputs":[{"name":"balance","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"symbol","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"string"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"}]')
contract = w3.eth.contract(address='0x40E64405F18e4FB01c6fc39f4F0c78df5eF9D0E0', abi=abi)
balance = contract.functions.balanceOf('0x7Ba83AC9243Ff520A28FC218758608F900E2d958').call(block_identifier=19649654)
print(balance)
# 976055241381593241650

# example of http request to get transaction
tx = requests.post('https://eth-pokt.nodies.app', json={"method":"eth_getTransactionByHash","params":["0xd8feb6cd2e76f738e2b42da99f9746ade1dc8e4034ae79acec01fda7b293e6c1"],"id":1,"jsonrpc":"2.0"}, headers={"Content-Type": "application/json"}).json()


What is your end goal?

@MohamedSohail I found a bug in multiprocessing using we3py lib, so I need to manage without it (github was reported)

Try using https://github.com/chaintool-py/chainlib-eth
